# Number of ways to arrange chess pieces

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

If every row and column of an 8×8 chessboard can only have odd numbers of pieces, what's the number of ways to arrange the pieces?
Here we assume that all pieces are indistinguishable.

Obviously, for a 1×1 board, we only have f(1)=1 way to arrange.

For the 2×2 board, f(2)=2, which is 'each row and column has 1 piece' and there are 2!=2 ways.

For the 3×3 board, first I consider 'each row and column has 1 piece' and this will give 3!=6 ways. Then another case is '1 row/column has 3 pieces, another 2 rows/columns have 1 piece', and we have 3 possible choices for the row/column which has 3 pieces, thus 3x3=9 in total. Finally, 'all rows/columns has 3 pieces' will contribute another way.

The total ways I got for a 3×3 board is then f(3)= 6+9+1=16.
It would be quite challenging for me to solve the 4×4 case. I also would like to know if the math induction approach is valid for this problem, which allows us to find a way of arranging pieces on an n*n board.

Comment: Arrange an $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ board any way you like and then use the final row and column to make everything odd in one possible way

Comment: I think you mean "all pieces are indistinguishable". In your 2x2 board, if the pieces were distinguishable, then there would be $2!$ arrangements with (e.g.) a black pawn in the first row and a white pawn in the second row, plus another $2!$ arrangements with a white pawn in the first row ad a black pawn in the second row.

Comment: @Henry, you need to consider what to do with the final square - if you fill in the first $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ sub-board arbitrarily, then you fill in the first $n-1$ places in the final row and the final column, how often will the first $n-1$ places in the final row have an odd number of pieces, but the first $n-1$ places in the final column have an even number of pieces? You need to say why in your answer.

Comment: @1Rock the answer is never (the parities of the $n\times(n-1)$ and $(n-1)\times n$ parts of the board will both be equal to the parity of $n-1$, and you can adjust for the parity of the $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ part of the board to see the parities of the $1\times (n-1)$ and $(n-1) \times 1$ parts will be equal to each other). My comment was trying to leave some things to the questioner